# Can I use Full-Text Search Functions in db_select()?

Tags: 8, database

Does it possible to use Full text search functions like `match() against()` with Drupal 8 database Api's OR any alternative to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

No. If you look at the internal [`Condition::match()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21Query%21Condition.php/function/Condition%3A%3Amatch/8.2.x) function that's used when building conditional statements with the `condition()` method, you can see the list of operators does not include the `MATCH()` `AGAINST()` operators. The cost of having a [DB abstraction layer](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!database.api.php/group/database/8.2.x) that supports different DBMS, is you can only support the greatest common feature among them; these operators are MySQL/Postgres specific.

In order to utilize these feature of your database, you'll need to use the [`Connection::query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Connection.php/function/Connection%3A%3Aquery/8.2.x) method to perform the query directly.